# Привести пример двух разных строк с одинаковыми хешами md5 или sha1

Tags: md5, sha

Везде предлагают алгоритмы для поиска коллизий, но мне просто нужен пример двух разных строк, у которых хэши md5 или sha1 совпадают.

Чтобы выполнялось условие:

```
md5(string1) == md5(string2)
```

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/are-there-two-known-strings-which-have-the-same-md5-hash-value

Comment: @Yaant честно сказать не нашёл там две строчки, которые бы дали один хэш. Есть какие то "якобы" разные строки в hex формате которые дают один хэш - но внешне они совпадают. Я бы хотел простой пример, если такой возможен)

Comment: @jekaby вы проверьте совпадают ли они действительно, а не внешне.